# Find difference between two time for verification token in Django

Tags: django

I am creating an app in Django where I have to send a token to a user but I want to make it expire
after 5 minutes, now the issue I am getting time from django field in this format

```
token_time = Token.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).last().user_token_timestamp
current time = datetime.now().time()
```

is there any way to find the time difference in minutes in pythonic way, although I have done by converting the time into string and then striping it  but it just feels like not a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract the current time from token time

```
 td = current_time - token_time
 mins = td.seconds / 60
```